# Hindman's theorem on coloring a set with $n$ colours

Tags: ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

[Hindman's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_set) states that if we colour $\mathbb{N}$ (positive integers) with a finite number of colours $c_1,\ldots,c_n$, then there exists a color $c_i$ and an infinite subset $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ such that every finite sum of elements in $A$ has the same colour.

But wouldn't this imply that each element of $A$ has the same colour? If $a,b \in A$ and the colour of $a$ and $b$ are different, then ... that's a contradiction, right?

Clearly I'm misunderstanding something. If someone could shed some light on this that would be great.

Comment: Of course all elements of this "special" set $A$ have the same color.

Comment: Yes, and e.g. if $a_1,a_2 \in A$ the color for $a_1+a_2$ would also have to be the same color $c_i$ as all the elements (which are sums of one term) of $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A sum of one term is still a sum.  So yes, your reasoning is correct--the set $A$ must be all the same color.

That the set itself also has the same color is also [made clear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_set#Hindman.27s_Theorem) by Wikipedia, emphasis mine:

> We can reformulate a special case of Hindman's Theorem in more familiar terms: Suppose the natural numbers are "colored" with $n$ different colors; each natural number gets one and only one of the $n$ colors.  Then there exists a color $c$ and an infinite set $D$ of natural numbers, **all colored with $\boldsymbol{c}$**, such that every finite sum over $D$ also has color $c$.

I previously erroneously claimed that it is equivalent that there exists an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, all of the same color, and closed under addition--the set of all finite sums of elements of $A$.
This is incorrect.  The difference is that "finite sum" refers here only to sums of a finite number of *distinct* elements.
I apologize for the error.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, thanks.

Comment: The statement that there's a monochromatic set that's closed under addition is **not** correct -- multiples are explicitly excluded by Hindman's Theorem, only *distinct* sums are guaranteed to be monochromatic. Otherwise, Hindman's Theorem would state that the notion of "subsemigroup" is partition regular -- which is false for almost all semigrous. For $\mathbb{N}$, first partition $\mathbb{N}$ into intervals of, e.g., exponentially growing size; then union the even/odd indexed intervals to get a partition. It's easy to see that for each $x$, $x+x$ would be in the other part of the partition.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Thanks for the catch, I figured I was missing something with that definition.  I apologize for the error.

Comment: No need to apologize. It is a good answer and a common mistake. There's the concept of partial semigroup which captures Hindman's theorem better this way.